# Is the map $\phi(r+4 \mathbb{Z})=r^3 + 4\mathbb{Z}$ well defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I would like to determine whether the following map is well-defined:
$$\gamma : \mathbb Z/ 4\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/ 4\mathbb Z$$
$$\phi (r+4\mathbb Z)=r^3+4\mathbb Z, r \in \mathbb Z$$
After a few trials, I believe that the map is well-defined. Therefore, I would like to prove: For $a=b$, we have $\phi (a) = \phi(b)$.

Here is my trial: Note that $$r \equiv 0,1,2,3 \, (mod 4),$$for all $r \in \mathbb Z$. Then $$r^3 \equiv 0,1,8,27 \equiv 0,1,0,3 \, (mod 4)$$

How can I proceed? I know that for $r$ in the same equivalent class, they will map to the same image. How can I write it precisely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $r+ 4 \Bbb{Z} = s + 4 \Bbb{Z}$, then $s=r+4k$.
Then
$$s^3-r^3 = (r+4k)^3 - r^3 = 4 \cdot \mbox{something}$$
so that $r^3 \equiv s^3 \mod{4}$, and the map is well defined.

Comment: In other words if $r+4 Z=s+4 Z$ then $r^3+4 Z=s^3+4 Z.$